# Relocating christening record for Margaret Morgan, believed to be 1808 at St James, Bristol, England?

Tags: england, vital-records, 1800s-decade, gloucestershire

I have asked a different question about my 3rd great grandmother Margaret Morgan previously in [Identifying photograph which may be Margaret Morgan (1808-1902) taken at Bridgend, Glamorgan, Wales?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6621/identifying-photograph-which-may-be-margaret-morgan-1808-1902-taken-at-bridgen)

However, this question has a different focus, which is on finding stronger evidence for her christening?

My current timeline for Margaret (copied from the earlier question) is:

- christened on 28 Aug 1808 at St James, Bristol, Gloucester. Father William Morgan and Mother Jane
- married Thomas Morgan on 20 Aug 1831 at St Bride's Minor, Glamorganshire, Wales
- in 1841 Census, aged 30 living at place (farm?) called Foesyrefoil (sp?), Coychurch, Thomas Morgan 38 Margaret Morgan 30 Thomas Morgan 9 Margaret Morgan 7 William Morgan 4 Ann Morgan 2 At same address but diff census record is Ann Griffith aged 69 (poss her mother?)
- in 1851 Census aged 43 living at Trebryn (sp?), Pencoed, with husband Thomas and six children. Birthplace given as City of Bristol. Thomas Morgan 42 Margaret Morgan 43 William Morgan 14 Catherine Morgan 8 Martha Morgan 6 John Morgan 4 Elizabeth Morgan 3 James Morgan 1
- in 1861 Census aged 53 living at Trabrin Beach (sp?), Coychurch with husband Thomas and two children. Birthplace given as Bristol. Thomas Morgan 52 Margret Morgan 53 Elizabeth Morgan 13 Edwin Morgan 6
- in 1871 Census aged 63, living at Tybryn, Coychurch, born in Bristol Thomas Morgan 62 Margaret Morgan 63 James Morgan 20
- in 1881 Census aged 73, living at Trebryn, Pencoed, born in Bristol, living with husband Thomas aged 72
- when and where she died is unknown but I think this (not yet obtained) may be her husband Thomas:

> NAME: Thomas Morgan ESTIMATED BIRTH YEAR: abt 1809 REGISTRATION YEAR:
>   1885 REGISTRATION QUARTER: Jan-Feb-Mar AGE AT DEATH: 76 REGISTRATION
>   DISTRICT: Pontypridd INFERRED COUNTY: Glamorganshire VOLUME: 11a PAGE:
>   325

It is her christening/baptism that I wish to focus on here.  I based the first dot point above on an IGI listing (believed to be a pre-2000) that my aunt provided me a few years ago which says:

> IGI Record from Family Search that a Margaret Morgan was Christened 28
>   August 1808 St James, Bristol, Gloucester. Father William Morgan and
>   Mother Jane

My problem is that I have not been able to locate this record (or any better candidate record) at either FamilySearch.org, Ancestry.com or FindMyPast.

Does anyone know of an alternative source that I may be able to use to try and re-locate this record?

Comment: I've found the record on Ancestry, Findmypast and Familysearch. What search terms are you using?

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl I suspect that the reason I had not found it before Feb 2015 is that a [new set of Gloucestershire Parish Registers came online](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/7898/19) since.

Comment: Doesn't explain why you didn't find it at the other two sites, which have had that dataset for years.... Source Information
Ancestry.com. England, Select Births and Christenings, 1538-1975 [database on-line]. Provo, UT, USA: Ancestry.com Operations, Inc., 2014.
Original data: England, Births and Christenings, 1538-1975. Salt Lake City, Utah: FamilySearch, 2013.

Comment: It isn't in Gloucestershire, England, Church of England Baptisms, Marriages and Burials, 1538-1813

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl it was over four years ago that I looked for those records and asked this question.  If they were there then, then I must simply have missed them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [FreeREG](http://www.freereg.org.uk/parishes/som/frontpage.shtml) this lists all the PR's that they have currently transcribed and also has links to other sites that may have what you are looking for. Also the [Forebears](http://forebears.co.uk/england/gloucestershire/bristol) site has lots of alternative links to try.

Also yesterday Ancestry released a load of Gloucestershire PR's on their site. As they are so new have you checked these yet?

Comment: After your answer I looked quickly at FreeREG without success and then double-checked Ancestry.com to find Name: Margaret Morgan
Gender: Female
Baptism Date: 28 Aug 1808
Baptism Place: St James, Bristol, Gloucester, England
Father: William Morgan
Mother: Jane
FHL Film Number: 1596534

Comment: That's great news.

Answer (score 0):

After receiving [@Colin's answer](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/7898/19) in Feb 2015 I looked quickly at FreeREG without success and then double-checked Ancestry.com to find:

> Name: Margaret Morgan Gender: Female Baptism Date: 28 Aug 1808 Baptism
>   Place: St James, Bristol, Gloucester, England Father: William Morgan
>   Mother: Jane FHL Film Number: 1596534

I suspect that the reason I had not found it originally is that a new set of Gloucestershire Parish Registers came online in between but it is possible that I just missed them.