# Identifying family in photo taken by Edwin Lott at Bridgend, Wales?

Tags: 19th-century, wales, photo-identification, glamorgan

[image: Family photo]

Can anyone identify the family in this photo taken by Edwin Lott at Nolton Studio Bridgend? I believe it's a Morgan family.

The reverse side of the photograph can be seen in [Dating photo by Edwin Lott from Nolton Studio at Bridgend, Glamorgan, Wales?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9800/dating-photo-by-edwin-lott-from-nolton-studio-at-bridgend-glamorgan-wales)

Comment: That's a great photo!  Would you be able to tell us more about the people that you think it could be, please?  The chances of someone recognizing the photo alone is near zero, but once it is given some context, our volunteer experts may be able to help rule out or give credence to some of the candidates.  If you have the reverse side of the photo available to scan, and if the system lets you, I would recommend adding that too.

Comment: As you can see from http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6621/identifying-photograph-which-may-be-margaret-morgan-1808-1902-taken-at-bridgen, the precise wording on the back could be helpful for determining the age of the photo.  Unlike the photo in my earlier question, the front of this one does not mention "Nolton Studio" but you have mentioned it in your question so I am thinking it must say that on the back.