# Dating photo by Edwin Lott from Nolton Studio at Bridgend, Glamorgan, Wales?

Tags: 19th-century, photo-identification, glamorgan

[image: Back of photo of unknown Morgan relative from Bridgend]

Does anyone know what years this image was used on Edwin Lott photos?

This was on the back of the unidentified family believed to be Morgan relatives which I posted in [Identifying family in photo taken by Edwin Lott at Bridgend, Wales?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9799/identifying-family-in-photo-taken-by-edwin-lott-at-bridgend-wales).

Comment: I am curious about whether you put this into a new question rather than using an edit to your existing question because you were unable to place two pictures in the same question?  It would have been much better to have them together.

Answer (score 2):

To try and date the photograph I used information in [Identifying photograph which may be Margaret Morgan (1808-1902) taken at Bridgend, Glamorgan, Wales?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6621/identifying-photograph-which-may-be-margaret-morgan-1808-1902-taken-at-bridgen) that I copied at the time from http://www.genuki.org.uk/big/wal/VicPhoto1.html.  Unfortunately, the GENUKI website is in the process of being upgraded to a content management system (11 Oct 2015) but I found it available again at http://www.genuki.org.uk/big/wal/Occupations/VicPhoto1#GLA.

Edwin Lott labelled like this with the wording on your photograph's reverse side in bold:

- LOTT Edwin 8 Nolton St, Bridgend 1875, 1884
- LOTT Edwin Nolton St, Bridgend 1880
- **LOTT Edwin Nolton Studio, Bridgend** 1891, 1895, 1901
- LOTT Edwin 9 Nolton Studio, Bridgend 1906, 1910, 1914, 1920

Based on that the photo may have been taken 1891-1901, but taking account of the “gap years” above could have been 1885-1905.  However, I do note that the appearance of the reverse in the photo at [Identifying photograph which may be Margaret Morgan (1808-1902) taken at Bridgend, Glamorgan, Wales?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6621/identifying-photograph-which-may-be-margaret-morgan-1808-1902-taken-at-bridgen) is much more elaborate, mentioning being "Under Royal Patronage", and so I am wondering whether your photo may be another variant (possibly earlier).